# Solve for $x$ in $x(x-4)>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I tried:

$$x(x-4)>0 \Leftrightarrow x > 0 \cdot (x-4) \lor x-4 > 0 \cdot x \Leftrightarrow x > 0 \lor x > 4$$

And thus I get $x > 0 \lor x > 4$, but the right answer is $x < 0 \lor x > 4$.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your work is very difficult to decipher as-is.

Comment: The product of two numbers is positive if and only if both numbers have the same sign, positive or negative. Hence, either $x,x+4$ are both positive or both negative. I did not understand the second step, so I can't say what definitely is wrong.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Haha, exactly what I thought with all the symbolic logic (see my answer). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've often found logical symbols just confuse the matter, so I'm going to use plain English here.

$(x)(x-4)>0$

For a product to be positive, EITHER both terms are positive (case 1) OR both terms are negative (case 2).

Case 1:

$x > 0$ AND $x > 4$. The latter case covers the former case completely, so you only require $x > 4$.

Case 2:

$x < 0$ AND $x < 4$. The former case covers the latter case completely, so you only require $x < 0$.

Those two cases are linked by an OR condition, so the final solution is $x < 0$ OR $x > 4$.

Comment: Definite +1 for plain English.

Comment: How did you get $x < 0$ and $x < 4$ in case 2?

Comment: @MarkRead, Deepak assumed that $x$ and $x-4$ were both negative and not zero so that the product is greater than 0. As a result this would be true when $x < 0$ and $x-4<0$ which gives us $x <0$ and $x<4$. Hope that helps!